# Using Floor/Ceil to round decimals to integer of 5

Tags: python, pandas, floor, ceil

I have been using the code below to handily round to 1dp where I needed the .5s to round upwards, e.g. I wanted a value such as 36.25 to round to 36.3, not 36.2.

```
def my_round(n, ndigits=1):
    try:
       part = n * 10 ** ndigits
       delta = part - int(part)
       # always round "away from 0"
       if delta >= 0.5 or -0.5 < delta <= 0:
           part = math.ceil(part)
       else:
           part = math.floor(part)
       val =  part/(10 ** ndigits)
    except ValueError:
       val = np.nan
    return val
```

I now need to round a different decimal column in a df to the nearest 5 whole numbers. Can anyone help suggest how I can tweak my original code above to do this? I need, for example, a value such as 702.5000 rounding to 705. Using the normal Round() it obviously goes to 700. In the example, all other normal rounding rules should apply e.g.

> 702.222 to  700,
>   707.466 to  705,
>   703.021 to 705

Comment: Hi, that is currently not even valid python code. Please fix the indentation first.

Comment: think that should be ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round to a certain number of decimal places, use this:

```
def my_round(x: float, round_to: float = 5, dp: int = 0) -> float: 
    round_to *= 10**dp 
    x *= 10**dp 
    return ((x + round_to / 2) // round_to * round_to) / 10**dp
```

Testing it:

```
values = [702.500, 702.222, 707.466, 703.021]
targets = [705., 700., 705., 705.]
assert [my_round(x, 5, 0) for x in values] == targets
assert my_round(3.25, 0.1, 1) == 36.3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_round(n):
    lower = (n//5)*5;
    upper = lower+5;

    if (n-lower)<(upper-n):
        return int(lower)
    return int(upper)

print(my_round(703.021))
```

The above program tries to find out the proper multiple of 5 before and after the given number.
Then it finds the differences between the lower and upper possible number and returns the number with least difference. This is as good as rounding.

Comment: This appears to be just what we need thank you Ashwin

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would be to divide by 5, round and then multiply by 5. It's purely mathematical fact that this will work.

`5*round(n/5)`

And there's no need for the if statement deciding on when to use `floor` or `ceil` since `round` already defaults to this logic.

EDIT: As pointed out this works for all values except those ending in 2.5 when requiring that this rounds up (in practice many examples won't need this).

As Ashwin's answer accomplishes this already, I'll give a fix to do it on one line without a function definition, though it's not pretty:

```
5 * (int(x/5) + 1 - round(x/5 % 1))
```

Or slightly cleaner with `ceil`:

```
5*(math.ceil(x/5) - round(x/5 % 1))
```

exploiting the the fact that round behaves as we would like from above.
Even better, define:

```
def my_round(x): return int(x + 1) - round(x % 1)
def round5(x): return 5*my_round(x/5)
```

to 'fix' the round function and create a nice `round5` function in 2 lines. This is what I'd do.

Comment: For `n=2.5` this rounds to `0`, not to `5` as @nn1234 wants, since you are still just using `round`.

Comment: Good point, I assumed OP was more worried about the rounding to a multiple of 5. In  that case the if statement logic is required

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the number you are trying to round by 5, then take its `round()` and multiply again by five:

```
num = 707.466
int = num / 5 # returns 141.4932
rounded = round(int) # returns 141
answer = rounded * 5 # 705
```

Or as a function:

```
def round_to_five(num):
    num = num / 5
    num = round(num)
    return num * 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
# my standard point to which rounding shoulding happen
>>> standard_nums = [700, 702, 705, 708]


# example value I am taking
>>> my_num = 702.5 


# this is how I would round my number
>>> ret = abs(standard_nums[0] - my_num)
>>> val = standard_nums[0]
>>> for each in standard_nums[1:]:
...     if abs(each - my_num) < ret:
...             ret = abs(each - my_num)
...             val = each
...
>>> ret # min diff I can find
0.5
>>> val # value you are lookin for
702
>>>

## this above has a complexity of O(N)
## where N is the size of your standard number
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use Python 3, would the following line do the job ?

`5*(x//5)+5*(x%5>=2.5)`

It seems to work for `x` being a scalar, `numpy.array` or a `pandas.series`